# Objects are not valid as a React child -> Build time error -> next js typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, build

**Return object from function in build time error ... when I build my app(npm run build). show me this error**

->Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, age}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

**That is my code**

```
const obj = {
    name:"A",
    age:20
}
function ObjFileReturn():[obj:{name:string,age:number}] {
  return [obj];
}
export default ObjFileReturn;
```

**The question is -> How can I return obj from a function using ts**

please help me and ignore my writing style.

Comment: Add more details about usage and console error stack.

Comment: This is my error message -> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: It will work when I run my code using (npm run dev).
It shows me an error when I compile it (npm run build).

Comment: This is the error link that I see in the console   -> https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bname%7D

Comment: I am trying to generate a static site page in the next js.

Comment: try to remove json.stringify to see if will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return the object as a component you need to first stringify the object or transform it from an object type. Objects are not valid JSX/React elements.

You can do:

```
type objType = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const obj: objType = {
    name: "A",
    age: 20
}

function ObjFileReturn() {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t'}</div>

export default ObjFileReturn;
```

JSON.stringify() converts the object to string which you can use inside a div to return from the functional comonent. The extra parameters in strigify pretty-print it so that it remains formatted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, buddy. 
I have another question. Could you please answer it?

Comment: Please chek out this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72065850/custom-hook-build-time-problem-react-typescript-and-next-js